# Can I disable congestion Control in QUIC in linux?

Tags: linux, networking, protocols

I want to know if I can somehow disable congestion control in QUIC.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the central design goals of QUIC was that the userspace, not the kernel, is in charge of congestion control.

So, if your QUIC application doesn't do congestion control: there's no congestion control.